# how to use jquery addclass on parent ul by counting li?

Tags: jquery

i need to addclass on my parent ul by count li onload. here is example of my ul li.

for example count li inside submenu and add class there.

or something else class name that define li count.

```html
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">top 1st menu</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">sub menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sub menu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">top 2nd menu</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">sub menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sub menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sub menu</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">sub menu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

hope its clean. if not please let me know i will provide screenshot to clear more.

thank you

Comment: you required solution with Javascript/Jquery?

Comment: please provide screenshot ? when you need to add class its on click event? add class on clicked element and its parent element?

Comment: @SandipPatel thank you i need jquery

Comment: @HareshVidja onload

Comment: every li parent UL have same class?

Comment: Hi @SandipPatel please check below that code works but i need sub2 and sub4 not 2 and 4 class

Comment: please check i have put validation for parent ul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("ul").addClass(function() {
    return ' ' + $(this).find(">li").length; //Change the class accordingly.
  });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1467/

With a prefix:

```
 $("ul").addClass(function() {
    return 'sub' + $(this).find(">li").length; //Change the class accordingly.
  });
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/1466/

Comment: thank you @k-k is it possible to use sub2 and sub4 not just 2 or 4 class

Answer (score 0):

you can **loop through ul** and find li

```
$("ul").each(function (a, b) {
        if (!$(this).hasClass("nav")) {
            $(this).addClass("Sub" + String(b.children.length));
        }
    });
```

Comment: hi sandip i need i`ve another problem please check this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38873344/how-to-append-class-on-li-and-ul-using-same-content

Comment: check there and confirm