# How to append class on li and ul using same content?

Tags: jquery

I need to addclass or append class name same from content. Here is example.

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">men</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">new arrival</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">top 2nd menu</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">go</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hello menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is what I want as final result onload:

```html
<ul>
  <li class="men">
    <a href="#">men</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="new-arrival"><a href="#">new arrival</a></li>
      <li class="about"><a href="#">about</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="top-2nd-menu">
    <a href="#">top 2nd menu</a>
    <ul>
      <li class="go"><a href="#">go</a></li>
      <li class="hello-menu"><a href="#">hello menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can you be more specific ? what class to whom ? what do you want to achieve ? what did you try ( JQ code )

Comment: @MihaiT yes please check i edit code. yes i want this done with jquery onload. i put there my current and what i need both code.

Comment: well added an answer below but it took longer to write all the explanation and it was too late :) glad you got your answer

Comment: thank you @MihaiT for your try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this with a little JQ .

**A.** first you need to find the `text` form each `a` that corresponds to each `li`.

to do that use the `text()` function **( [info here](http://api.jquery.com/text/) )**

**B.** then if you have more than one word as `text` you need to `join` the words with `-` using the `replace()` method **([info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace))**.

this is because if you don't join the words ( put "-" between them ), for example for text `top 2nd menu`  then the `li` will have 3 separate classes instead of only one. so by using the `replace()` method you get the wanted result, respectively `top-2nd-menu`

**C.** and then add class to your `li`  with `attr("class","nav-" + addcl)` ( [**info here**](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) )

this way you add whichever word you want before the text ( `addcl` ) you got from points A and B

```js
$("li").each(function(){


var litext = $(this).children("a").text()
var addcl = litext.replace(/\s/g, '-').toLowerCase()
$(this).attr('class', 'nav-' +  addcl);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">men</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">new arrival</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">top 2nd menu</a>
      <ul>
      <li><a href="#">go</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">hello menu</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: add class `nav` to the `ul` ? you can do that directly in `html` . or you need to do that with jQuery ?

Comment: i want nav- in each class like nav-hello-menu and nav-go

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this you can provide a function to the `addClass()` method which returns the `text()` of the `a` element, after replacing the spaces for `-`. Try this:

```js
$('li').addClass(function() {
  return $(this).children('a').text().replace(/\s/g, '-');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">men</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">new arrival</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">top 2nd menu</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">go</a></li>          
      <li><a href="#">hello menu</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("ul li a").each(function (a, b) {           
       $(this).parent().addClass(b.text.replace(/\s/g, '-'));
});
```

Comment: thank you again for help but its not working. below code works for me.

Comment: can i know issue with this code, because it work here

Comment: please upvote/accept in all given answers if working

Comment: don't know its not working for me above code works well. sorry sandip do have some more question hope you will help and will provide you upvote/accept in future.

Comment: it's not working because in case you have 2 or more words as text of the `a` , the parent `li` gets 2 or more separate classes instead of only one

Comment: @SandipPatel help me i ve new question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38895553/how-to-append-image-inside-ul-with-new-li-jquery