# how to append image inside ul with new li onload (jquery)?

Tags: jquery

how to append image inside ul with new li (jquery)?

move image to new li and new addclass on ul

```html
<img src="img" class="navimg">
<ul class="nav">
  <li>nav 1</li>
  <li>nav 1</li>
</ul>

 
<ul class="nav newclass">
  <li>nav 1</li>
  <li>nav 1</li>
   <li><img src="img" class="navimg"></li>
</ul>
```

here is another question.

```html
<div class="nav1">
<ul>
  <li>nav 1</li>
  <li>nav 1</li> 
</ul>
</div>

<a href="" class="nav"><img src="img"  /></a>

<div class="nav2">
<ul>
  <li>nav 1</li>
  <li>nav 1</li> 
</ul>
</div>


<a href="" class="nav2"><img src="img"  /></a>
```

is it possible to match same name css and move   `<a href="" class="nav2"><img src="img"  /></a>` inside same class with new li `<div class="nav2">
    <ul>
      <li>nav 1</li>
      <li>nav 1</li> 
    </ul>`

Comment: can i have your latest code

Comment: please check above code need that onload too.

Comment: <li><img src="img" class="imgforli"></li> need to add this and class="nav imageclass" on ul

Comment: please specify your initial html and final html

Comment: check once i ve update my question after and before

Comment: check my answer now, may help you

Comment: hi sandip did you checked my new question just below old one?

Comment: it is good if you post separate question with initial html and final html

Comment: @SandipPatel please check here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910065/jquery-move-blocks-element-if-class-match hope its clear for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {        
    var imgTag = $(".imgforli").clone(true);
    var newHtml = "<li>" + imgTag[0].outerHTML + "</li>";       
    $(".imgforli").remove();
    $("ul").append(newHtml).addClass("newclass");
});
```

Comment: need to wrap that image with li

Comment: yes it works but i m thinking something else too so i will update my question again. will be same but some other logic

Comment: hi again i've add another question just below old, can you please check once.

Comment: Can you please also up vote in all given answer with previous one if helpful to you

Answer (score 1):

Try following code.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  addImage();
});
function addImage(){
  var html = "<li><img src='img' class='imgforli' /></li>";
  $('.nav').addClass('imageclass').append(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#"><img src="img" class="imgforli" /></a>

need to move above image inside ul with new li

<ul class="nav">
  <li>nav 1</li>
  <li>nav 1</li>
   <li><img src="img" class="imgforli"/></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi need that onload

Comment: on page onload you want to do the same thing what I've done ?

Comment: can you remove click and all unwanted js i m not programmer

Comment: removed clicked functionality, please check

Comment: is it possible to move any image there will lots of image src so i wanna any img src with same class need to move on ul with new li

Answer (score 0):

When the `document` is `ready` ...

select the `ul` with class `nav` and `append` ...

a new `<li></li>` element which will have `append`ed ...

all the `img` elements with class `navimg` and ...

finally add a `newclass` class to the `ul`.

Now, in code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul[class="nav"]').append(
                $("<li></li>").append(
                        $('img[class="navimg"]')
                )
        ).addClass('newclass');
});
```

Comment: thank you but i need to add new class too <ul class="nav newclass">

Comment: $(document).ready(function(){
        $('ul[class="nav"]').addClass('newclass').append(
          
                $("<li></li>").append(
                        $('img[class="imgforli"]')
                )
        );
});

Comment: What do you mean with that comment?

Comment: this works for me i just use $('ul[class="nav"]').addClass('newclass').append and it works

Comment: With that code you just add the `newclass` to that `ul`. With the code in my answer you do everything you want: move the images + add the new class. Evert Iine is explained before the code, so I think you cannot have any doubt.