# jQuery move blocks element if class match

Tags: jquery

class won't be fixed so need to find same unique 2 class with div and ul and move div inside ul with wrap li. at last when all done then add new addclass on ul

check screenshot my current situation - https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-aBOQ69HXqbWVhLTWhzWHFoQlE/view?usp=sharing

**these menu exist on html**

```html
   

<div class="nav1">
<ul>
  <li>menu a</li>
  <li>menu a</li> 
</ul>
</div>


<div class="nav2">
<ul>
  <li>menu a</li>
  <li>menu a</li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

```
**these block will be add somewhere else**
```

```html
 
<div class="nav1"><img src="img"  /></div>

<div class="nav2"><img src="img"  /></div>
```

**Final output.**

```html
   

<div class="nav1 newfixedclass">
<ul>
  <li>menu a</li>
  <li>menu a</li> 
 <li><div class="nav1"><img src="img"  /></div></li> 
</ul>
</div>


<div class="nav2 newfixedclass">
<ul>
  <li>menu a</li>
  <li>menu a</li> 
  <li><div class="nav2"><img src="img"  /></div></li> 
</ul>
</div>
```

```html
  <nav class="navigation">
    <ul>
     <li class="nav-women">
        <a class="level-top" href="women"><span>women</span></a>
        <ul class="level0">
          <li class="nav-features">
            <a href="women/features"><span>FEATURES</span></a>
            <ul class="level1">
              <li class="nav-new-arrivals">
                <a href="women/features/new-arrivals"><span>New Arrivals<span></a>
              </li>
           </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-categories">
            <a href="women/categories"><span>CATEGORIES</span></a>
            <ul class="level1">
              <li class="nav-sweaters">
                <a href="#"><span>Sweaters</span></a>
              </li>            
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-mens">
        <a class="level-top" href="mens"><span>mens</span></a>
        <ul class="level0">
          <li class="nav-features">
            <a href="mens/features"><span>FEATURES</span></a>
            <ul class="level1 submenu sub0">
              <li class="nav-new-arrivals">
                <a href="mens/features/new-arrivals"><span>New Arrivals</span></a>
              </li>
                         </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-categories">
            <a href="mens/categories"><span>CATEGORIES</span></a>
            <ul class="level1">
              <li class="nav-bags">
                <a href="mens/categories/bags"><span>Bags</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-blazers">
                <a href="mens/categories/blazers"><span>Blazers</span></a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-ties">
                <a href="mens/categories/ties"><span>Ties</span></a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
 </nav>
  
  
  <div class="nav-women"><img src="http://images.apple.com/v/home/ct/images/promos/public_betas_medium.jpg"></div>
 <div class="nav-mens"><img src="http://images.apple.com/v/home/ct/images/promos/public_betas_medium.jpg"></div>
```

Comment: don't see your JS code...!

Comment: <div class="nav1"><img src="img"  /></div>: this tag also exist in page?

Comment: "nav*": prefix is always nav there or different?

Comment: @SandipPatel  yes this will add later in some where body

there is no fix prefix


is it possible to match css name and move

Comment: @vijayP sorry i m not developer so i don't now anything this is just my question. i`m hoping for full working js.

Comment: @SandipPatel i've got somthing nav-xxx you can use nav-

Comment: i m bit confuse to change with my original stuff can you check once above i put new html code.

Comment: @SandipPatel  hi again. can you please update that code. need to find div width and add same width on LI after we move that div top ul li.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i have put your HTML as per my understanding and solution of your query in script.

```
<div class="nav1">
    <ul>
        <li>menu 11</li>
        <li>menu 22</li>
    </ul>
</div>


<div class="nav2">
    <ul>
        <li>menu 33</li>
        <li>menu 44</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="nav1"><img src="~/Images/bullet.png" /></div>
<div class="nav2"><img src="~/Images/bullet.png" /></div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div[class^='nav'] img").each(function (a, b) {                
            var imgTag = $(this).closest("div[class^='nav']").clone(true);
            var parentDivClass = imgTag.attr("class");
            $(this).closest("div[class^='nav']").remove();

            var newHtml = "<li>" + imgTag[0].outerHTML + "</li>";
            $("div[class^=" + parentDivClass + "] ul:first").append(newHtml);
            $("div[class^=" + parentDivClass + "]:first").addClass("newfixedclass");
        }); 
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do it by this,

```
$("div[class^=nav]:has(ul)").each(function(){
 $("ul", this)
    .append($("<li>")
       .append($("div."+ this.className + ":has(img) img")))
          .closest("div").addClass("newClassFixed");
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/s3ogubps/1/)

Yes you can move the div directly,

```
$("div[class^=nav]:has(ul)").each(function(){
 $("ul", this)
    .append($("<li>")
       .append($("div."+ this.className + ":has(img)")))
          .closest("div").addClass("newClassFixed");
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/s3ogubps/3/)

Comment: is it possible to move that div too inside li